# Spring Resource Loader SpEL error - EL1004E:(pos 24)

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-batch, spring-el

I am trying to access data from S3 bucket with the below  approach.
Created a SpringInjection class

```
public class SpringResourceInjection {

    @Inject
    public AmazonS3 s3client2;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public Resource s3Resource;


    public Resource getS3Resource() {
        return s3Resource;
    }

    public void setS3Resource(Resource s3Resource) {
        this.s3Resource = s3Resource;
    }
}
```

and Autowire the bean in my application context

```
<bean id="springResourceInjection" class="com.xx..SpringResourceInjection" scope="step">
    <property name="s3Resource" value="s3:// + ${awsBucketName} + / + #{stepExecutionContext['fileResource']}"/>
</bean>
```

and call the getResource method through sPEL for the resource variable

```
<bean id="itemreader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
<property name="resource" value="#{springResourceInjection.getS3Resource()}"/>
```

and i get the error saying the method cannot be found of type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18 is there something wrong in my configuration. Please help.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.itemreader' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 24): Method call: Method getS3Resource() cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18 type
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:548)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:341)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.open(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 24): Method call: Method getS3Resource() cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18 type
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:146)

Answer (score 1):

*Quick-and-dirty attempt try: `#{springResourceInjection.S3Resource}`.*

Scoped beans which are proxyfied with a standard java proxy doesn't expose concrete class methods.
You have 2 choice:

1. Make `SpringResourceInjection` an interface and with S3Resource accessors
2. Use CGLIB to create proxy

The first solution is quite simple, the second one requires more work (you can find a lot of info on SO).

As last word: why are you mixing xml and java config? Is usually a bad idea; make a choice and go ahead.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response step one works for me. The reason I am converting a Java config to XML is due to my entire application is XML based.